# How to retrieve mutiple images from url and display them in a gallery in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, imagedownload

I want to develop a gallery which can display images from various Http url's. I am downloading the image through `AsyncTask`. To download multiple images I have to use same `AsyncTask` many times for different url's. Its getting very slow. How should I proceed?
 Is `AsyncTask` need at all to download the image? Please guide me how should I go about in this app?
 I don't have much idea about threading.

Comment: Depends on how many images your are downloading. Its better if you keep clearing your cache memory. And download them in a queue rather than burst approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to refer this [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to fulfill your purpose.

This Example provide a reusable instrument for asynchronous image loading, caching and displaying.

It has the same example which you are looking for(i.e. download the image from the different URL's and Set in Gallery/GridView/ListView).

Hope this helps ... :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have any idea how to save a particular image to sd card?

Comment: For that i suggest you to ask separate question and my above answer is helpful to you,don't forget to accept it... :)